# Как ограничить ввод пользователя определёнными символами?

Tags: c#, .net-5

Делаю небольшой калькулятор по мере изучения шарпа и хотелось бы узнать, как ограничить ввод символов пользователем до определённых заданных? Видел где-то очень простой и быстрый вариант, но найти его заново так и не смог. Калькулятор хочу сделать на основе перевода ввода пользователя в char-массив (мало ли нужно для решения проблемы).
Подробнее о вводе: пользователь вводит выражение, на этом этапе мне нужно запретить ему писать символы, кроме цифр и знаков операций.

Comment: Ввод куда вам надо ограничить?

Comment: Консоль, WinForms, ещё что-то - куда ввод? Непонятно. И подробнее про ограничение - определённым списком допустимых символов хотите ограничить?

Comment: Если речь идёт про Console.ReadLine(), то никак не ограничить

Comment: Прошу прощения за долгий ответ. Пользователь вводит выражение в консоль, и мне нужно, чтобы он не мог писать ничего, кроме цифр и символов *, \, +, -.

Answer (score 0):

Есть вариант брать первые N значений. В C# 8.0 появилась возможность указывать диапазон:

```cs
var value = Console.ReadLine()[0..5];
```

В примере я выбрал из строки первые 5 символов.

Comment: Это обрежет строку, но не ограничит ввод только определенных символов.

Comment: Если честно, я даже не понял что он имел ввиду "ограничить".

Comment: Тогда не стоит спешить с ответом, а попросить автора дополнить вопрос.

Comment: Отредактировал описание.